# Handling spaces tabs and new lines in ReactJS rendering

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to render a string in reactjs Dialog box. The string contains /n /t spaces. I wanted it to render preserving all the spaces and newlines. I have tried many ways to achieve this but none of it worked.

My backend Python API call returns a response object which contains a string in data

```
response.data = "Line 1 \n Line2 \n Line3"
return response
```

ReactJS Dialog content has something like this

```
<DialogContent>
<div style={{ whiteSpace: "pre-wrap" }}>{content} </div>
</DialogContent>
```

Function which populates the content field

```
resp = await getContent(param);
await this.setState({
      content: resp["data"]
    });
```

Dialog content never preserves the spaces it is rendered as it is in a plain string.
For the sake of testing if I assign the same string to a tmp variable it works, not sure why the returned content from API call doesn't get rendered as expected

```
//Working if the same text is assigned to a variable
var tmp = "Line 1 \n Line2 \n Line3"
await this.setState({
      content: tmp
    });
```

Following are some of the approaches that I tried but none of them worked:

1. I have tried to convert the string to Blob and use FileReader to
   render the content
2. Tried `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. No luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pre` tag to wrap the content. `pre` tag preserves both spaces and line breaks.

So you can do

```
<DialogContent>
  <pre>{content}</pre>
</DialogContent>
```

Comment: It was displaying horizontally as a long line `Line1 \n Line2 \n Line3`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by returning a proper string from server-side.

```
result = "Line 1 \n Line2 \n Line3"
response.data =  result.decode('string-escape')
return response
```